# Stripe Webhooks, AWS Lambda Function URL, Raw Request Body Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, stripe-payments, webhooks

I deployed an AWS Lambda Node.js function that is triggered by the "Function URL" feature. The URL/function is registered in Stripe's webhooks and should be called when specific Stripe events occur. The Lambda function doesn't seem to have access to the raw, original request body and throws the following error:

Error:

```
Webhook Error: Webhook payload must be provided as a string or a Buffer 
(https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html) instance representing the _raw_ request body.
Payload was provided as a parsed JavaScript object instead.
Signature verification is impossible without access to the original signed material.
```

A custom mapping template (often suggested when using API Gateway) isn't an option as the Function URL feature doesn't provide access to the underlying gateway. Is there another way to access the raw, original body?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out, Lambda already provides the raw, original POST request body in the `event.body` property without making any modifications to it. There is no need to create a mapping or even reverse the "JSON.stringified" `event.body` value.

#### Example (doesn't work ❌)

```js
// ... imports

exports.handler = async (event) => {
  // ...
    
  const stripeEvent = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(
    JSON.parse(event.body), // doesn't work
    event.headers['stripe-signature'],
    secrect,
  );

  // ...
};
```

#### Example (does work ✅)

```js
// ... imports

exports.handler = async (event) => {
  // ...
    
  const stripeEvent = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(
    event.body, // works
    event.headers['stripe-signature'],
    secrect,
  );

  // ...
};
```